# после использования playsound.playsound(unique_filename), выходят новые ошибки, не знакомые мне

Tags: python-3.x

[image]

Я импортировал playsound и после использование выходит ошибка "'\n    ' + errorBuffer.value.decode())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd3 in position 0: invalid continuation byte"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте в 16 строке добавить `.` перед `mp3`:

`unique_filename = 'audio_' + str(random.randint(0,100000)) + '.mp3'`